# Will Broadcast receiver keep run after I have installed .apk file with Broadcast receiver?

Tags: android

I have read the document http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/08/android-broadcast-receiver-enable-and.html,
I think the Broadcast receiver AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver will keep run even if I exit the app, 
In order to stop the Broadcast receiver, I have to run the app again and click Disable Broadcast Receiver button, right?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android='http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android'
    xmlns:tools='http://schemas.android.com/tools'
    android:layout_width='match_parent'
    android:layout_height='match_parent' 
    android:orientation='vertical'>

     <Button
        android:layout_width='fill_parent'
        android:layout_height='wrap_content'
        android:padding='@dimen/padding_medium'
        android:text='@string/start_repeating_alarm'
        android:onClick='startRepeatingAlarm'
        tools:context='.EnableDisableBroadcastReceiver' />
     <Button
       android:layout_width='fill_parent'
       android:layout_height='wrap_content'
       android:padding='@dimen/padding_medium'
       android:text='@string/cancel_alarm'
       android:onClick='cancelAlarm'
       tools:context='.EnableDisableBroadcastReceiver' />

    <Button
        android:layout_width='fill_parent'
        android:layout_height='wrap_content'
        android:padding='@dimen/padding_medium'
        android:text='@string/enable_broadcast_receiver'
        android:onClick='enableBroadcastReceiver'
        tools:context='.EnableDisableBroadcastReceiver' />
   <Button
       android:layout_width='fill_parent'
       android:layout_height='wrap_content'
       android:padding='@dimen/padding_medium'
       android:text='@string/disable_broadcast_receiver'
       android:onClick='disableBroadcastReceiver'
       tools:context='.EnableDisableBroadcastReceiver' />

</LinearLayout>


<resources>
    <string name='app_name'>EnableDisableBroadcastReceiver</string>
    <string name='enable_broadcast_receiver'>Enable Broadcast Receiver</string>
    <string name='disable_broadcast_receiver'>Disable Broadcast Receiver</string>
    <string name='start_repeating_alarm'>Start Repeating Alarm</string>
    <string name='cancel_alarm'>Cancel Alarm</string>
    <string name='menu_settings'>Settings</string>
    <string name='title_activity_enable_disable_boradcast_receiver'>EnableDisableBoradcastReceiver</string>
</resources>



package com.code4reference.enabledisablebroadcastreceiver;
import java.text.Format;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

 final public static String ONE_TIME = 'onetime';
 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

         //You can do the processing here update the widget/remote views.
         StringBuilder msgStr = new StringBuilder();
         //Format time.
         Format formatter = new SimpleDateFormat('hh:mm:ss a');
         msgStr.append(formatter.format(new Date()));

         Toast.makeText(context, msgStr, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

 }
}




package com.code4reference.enabledisablebroadcastreceiver;

import com.example.enabledisablebroadcastreceiver.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class EnableDisableBroadcastReceiver extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    /**
     * This method gets called when 'Start Repeating Alarm' button is pressed.
     * It sets the repeating alarm whose periodicity is 3 seconds.
     * @param view
     */
    public void startRepeatingAlarm(View view)
    {
        AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager)this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);
        //After after 2 seconds
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000 * 4 , pi); 
        Toast.makeText(this, 'Started Repeating Alarm', Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
 /**
  * This method gets called when 'cancel Alarm' button is pressed.
  * This method cancels the previously set repeating alarm.
  * @param view
  */
    public void cancelAlarm(View view)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.cancel(sender);
        Toast.makeText(this, 'Cancelled alarm', Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    /**
     * This method enables the Broadcast receiver registered in the AndroidManifest file.
     * @param view
     */
   public void enableBroadcastReceiver(View view){
    ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(this, AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver.class);
    PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();

    pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
    Toast.makeText(this, 'Enabled broadcast receiver', Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
   /**
    * This method disables the Broadcast receiver registered in the AndroidManifest file.
    * @param view
    */
   public void disableBroadcastReceiver(View view){
    ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(this, AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver.class);
    PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();

    pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
    Toast.makeText(this, 'Disabled broadcst receiver', Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The broadcastreceiver should be fired, though it's technically not "running".

Comment: Thanks, will the broadcastreceiver  keep monitor even if I close the app?